# Unable to create dynamic instances of child class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, instance, subclass

I am creating a student registration program using inheritance, in which I want to create dynamic instances of student as entered by the user when prompted about total students but I am unable to do so.
Any help will be appreciated.

> 

```
import java.util.*;

class Course{
    static Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    String courseName;
    String preReq;
    static int totalStudents;

    Course(){
        System.out.println("Course Details:");
        System.out.print("Enter name of course: ");
        courseName=input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter pre-requisite: ");
        preReq=input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Class Details:");
        System.out.print("Enter no# of students: ");
        totalStudents=input.nextInt();
    }
}
class Student extends Course{
    String studentName;
    String studentCms;
    static int count=0;
    String confirm;

    Student(){
        count+=1;
        System.out.println("Student Details:");
        System.out.println("Enter name of student #"+count+": ");
        studentName=input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter CMS id of student #"+count+": ");
        studentCms=input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Y/y to register in course: ");
        confirm=input.next();
    }
}

public class CourseRegistration{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Student ob=new Student();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your specific issue? You wrote what you want to do, but not what is not working...

Comment: Apart from that: why is a `Student` derived from a `Course`? Certainly a student is not a specialized version of a course...

Comment: I can't create dynamic instances of student class.

Comment: Sure, you already said so in the question. But what does that mean, _exactly_? Do you get an error? Which? Tell us!

Comment: I have extended Student from Course because student object should contain the info about course.

Comment: Only a single instance is created, how do I create n instances? Where n is asked before.

Comment: That is not how you design a class hierarchy. You miss understood how that works. If a student object should contain a list of courses the student takes, then it should hold a list of course objects. That has _nothing_ to do with inheritance. A student class might inherit from a "person" class maybe.

Comment: You create multiple student instances by calling the `new` operator multiple times _and storing the result in separate objects_ , for example a `List` of students.

Comment: Note, too, that just because you *can* perform I/O in a constructor does not mean it's a good idea.

Comment: How do I make the student hold a list of course objects?

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, not to perform I/O operations in constructor next time.

Comment: I have to keep this note in mind while writing this program:
https://imgur.com/gallery/4pEzcSY